# Getting date and time in a trimmed way

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert a date and time into db in a format like this:

"20 May, 2013 at 5:45"

and if I want to show it in format 2 mins ago, just now, or 6 months ago etc., how can i do it.. :)

Can any one suggest me how to do this please,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you *want* to store a date/time value in a database as text? It's a fundamental mistake IMO.

Comment: You should store data in the database, and leave the formatting to the UI.

Comment: It is a mistake. Suppose you want to do searching or ordering on that field, what sort of code (supposing that it is possible) you need to write  to perform these simple operations?

Comment: @Tim: Can you just give an example on how to do that.?

Comment: Did you guys noticed this comment date format and the way its displaying like 3 mins ago, 2 months ago etc., so if I want to display like that how can I do it.. :)

Comment: You'll have to compute the difference between the date stored in the database (which should be a date/time vlaue) and the current date in the UI.  This is an entirely different question than what you originally asked.  I suggest you edit the title accordingly so it more matches what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its completely wrong to store date/date time data as string, you could use the `ToString` overload to specify the format:

```
var stringedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM',' yyyy 'at' H':'mm");
```

Comment: Will you please let me know why its wrong to store date/date time as string in db..

Comment: @Kaushik 1) you can have index on `datetime` type. 2) `datetime` type requires only 4 bytes of memory. 3) you can reformat `datetime` type to string as u want. 4) you can use `date` type for only 3 bytes of memory. 5) you can order your rows by `datetime` type. 6) you can compare `datetime` types. 7) you can add and subtract `datetime` types.

Answer (score 1):

Databases exist to store data and to let you ask and answer questions about them.  Applications come and go; data may last forever.  So, what sort of questions might you ask?  Granted, we don't know the problem domain, so these are just guesses.

> How many orders did we fulfill in the last 7 days?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) "Orders last week" FROM ORDERS
WHERE
     orderDate >= SYSDATE - 7  -- Oracle code
```

If you've turned the date into a string, you can't do this.

> Who has overdue library books?  Which ones?

```
SELECT u,id, u.first_name, u.last_name, b.id, b.book_name
FROM User u
JOIN Book b ON u.id = b.borrower_id
WHERE b.due_date < SYSDATE
AND b.returned = 0    -- Oracle doesn't have "BOOLEANS" yet.
```

You can do date arithmetic; adding or subtracting a number from a date datum gives the date that many days later or earlier.  There are functions that give "the next Tuesday after a date" or "The first of the year."  Your storing the date as a string makes all that closed off for you.

Suppose you need to format your date for the French division of your company.  Could you do that with your date strings?  Leave formatting for your application, not for the database.

This is an example of the importance of the Model-View-Controller architecture.  The model, the part that holds the data, should be independent of any particular application so it can work with any application, and a database is certainly part of the model.

I don't know C#, but similar code exists in SQL-Server, which I'm guessing you use.